# putting the first player on a left side python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can you please give me some hints or help me to write a code on python to show the starting player on the left side always? Actually, sometimes the char1 and sometimes the char2 starts the game, how can I write a code to show on the left the char that starts the game, until the game finishes, here in this code it shows always the char1, I tried to make some changes by changing the statements, but then each turn was changing the order of the chars, actually I want to stay for example if the char2 starts the game I want him to show on the left side until the game finishes. in the end of the code is the output of the actual code. so for the example here the second player it is shown on right side but i want him to be shown on the left side until the game finishes because he is the player who starts the game.
Thank You.
With Respect Marshal Alife

```
import random

# ---

def game():

    char1 = raw_input("Player One: ")

    while char1 == "":
        char1 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")

    char2 = raw_input("Player two: ")
    while char2 == char1:
        char2 = raw_input(char1 + " name is taken, please choose another name: ")
    while char2 == "":
        char2 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
    print char1, "and", char2, "welcome to the game."

    # ---

    health1 = health2 =100

    print char1,"[HP]"+"[%d]"%health1, '|' * (health1/2),
    print char2,"[HP]"+"[%d]"%health2, '|' * (health2/2)

    toss = random.randint(0, 1)

    if toss == 0:
        print char1, "will start the game"
    else:
        print char2, "will start the game"

    # ---

    while health1 > 0 and health2 > 0:
        if toss == 0:
            n = input(char1 + " select magnitude force between 1 and 50: ")
            if 50>=n>=1:
                if n > random.randint(1, 51):
                    print "you missed the chance"
                    print char1,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health1, '|' * (health1 / 2), " " * (50 - health1 / 2),
                    print char2,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health2, '|' * (health2 / 2), " " * (50 - health2 / 2)
                    toss= 1
                else:
                    health2 -= n
                    print char1,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health1, '|' * (health1 / 2), " " * (50-health1/2),
                    print char2,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health2, '|' * (health2 / 2), " " * (50-health2/2)
                    toss = 1 # change player
            else:
                print "n should be between 1 and 50"
        else:
            n = input(char2 + " select magnitude force between 1 and 50: ")
            if 50 >= n >= 1:
                if n > random.randint(1, 51):
                    print "you missed the chance"
                    print char1,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health1, '|' * (health1 / 2), " " * (50 - health1 / 2),
                    print char2,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health2, '|' * (health2 / 2)
                    toss= 0
                else:
                    health1 -= n
                    print char1,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health1, '|' * (health1 / 2), " " * (50 - health1 / 2),
                    print char2,"[HP]" + "[%d]" % health2, '|' * (health2 / 2)
                    toss = 0 # change player
            else:
                print "n should be between 1 and 50"
    # ---

    if health1 > 0:
        print char1, 'wins'
    else:
         print char2, 'wins'

game()

    # ---

while True:
    c=raw_input("Do you want to continue Yes or No: ")
    if c=="Yes":
        print "Welcome to the game again"
        game()
    elif c=="No":
        print "Good bye"
        break #return game()

Player One: marshal
Player two: alife
marshal and alife welcome to the game.
marshal [HP][100] |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| alife [HP][100] ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
alife will start the game
alife select magnitude force between 1 and 50: 10
you missed the chance
marshal [HP][100] ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  alife [HP][100] ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
marshal select magnitude force between 1 and 50:
```

Comment: You should narrow down your question and provide perhaps some output of the program as it is now as well as your desired output. As it is now, we'll have to dig into your entire code.

Comment: @Yohst here you go brother i entered the output here you can have a look is beneath the code

Comment: So it seems you want in the example you provided, 'alife' to be printed from the left under/above 'marshal' ?  If so, you just need to print a newline character at the end (\n)

Comment: @Yohst, no bro, i want them in the same line, but for example if 'if marshal' starts the game to show 'marshal' on the left side until the game finishes and if the 'alife' starts the game, to show the 'alife' of the left side of the line until the game finishes

Comment: If my answer below helped, let me know by upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your 'app' is currently hard-coded on the char1/char2 sequence, the best would be to break that. One way to do this is to have char1 and char2 be members of a list. e.g. `characters= [char1, char2]`  So the section around 'toss' becomes:

`first = toss
second = 1 - toss
print characters[first], "will start the game"`

the sections where you do the stats maintaining and printing will need to be updated in a similar fashion (so your health score goes into a list also).  Hope this helps...